# Play the video in two view controllers from where the previous video stopped

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have a table view controller that has a video view in each cell.

Each cell has a play button, slider and a full screen button.

I have implemented logic for playing , pausing and seeking the video using AVPlayerLayer.

When I click on the full screen button I am moving to another view controller where I will play the video in full screen in portrait and landscape mode

When I move to the full screen controller I want the video to play from where it was playing in the previous view controller.

And when I move back to the previous view controller the video should play from where it played in the full screen controller.

How can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented same for an audio player which has a mini player and tapping on it will open in full screen.

I have detached audio player from UI. Created singleton class of player which will update UI. So there will be only one instance of player which will update multiple UI in sync.

You can implement same logic for your player.

Comment: Can you share a link of your project?

Comment: @A.S I have a fully built project so can't able to share the code. However, you can get lots of example on StackOverflow itself.